# Open OFFICE CALC Macro's: how to get the old data that was in a cell after it had been changed?

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

I did a macro and used ChartDataChangeEvent to get a value of a cell after it had been changed, but i need the old value too for going to a specific column in another sheet and changing there the value according to the cell that had been changed.

is there a way to get the old data(before modification)?
(i don't want to copy all the sheet, because my tables are very big and it will take a long time).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud here, would this be a viable path: create a script based "on data change" (executes every time when data is modified by user). Then copy the "new" data from the active cell, then perform an "undo", to get the old data back, copy the old data, then put the new data back where it was. Don't know if you would programmatically have access to the internal undo stack, because that would be easier.